# Как в Unity Пустить луч только на 1 объект?

Tags: unity3d

Как в Unity Пустить луч только на 1 объект?

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform start, end;
    bool magnit = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);          
            transform.position = new Vector3(ray.origin.x, transform.position.y, 0);
            magnit = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            //magnit = false;
        }

        Magnit();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "blockPos(Clone)")
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(col.gameObject.transform.position.x,col.gameObject.transform.position.y);
        }
    }

    public void Magnit()
    {
        if (magnit)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(start.position, end.position, Color.red);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(start.position, end.position);
            if (hit.collider)
            {
                hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position, transform.position, Time.deltaTime * 3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот мой код.
Player пускает луч на объекты. Они стоят друг за другом. Притягивается вначале 1 потом 2 3 4.

Как мне сделать чтобы притягивался только самый первый? 2 притяниться когда 1 не будет. 3 когда 2 ит.д.

Comment: Заведите переменную еще одну булеву, которая будет отвечать за то, что сейчас уже магнититься объект.`private bool isМagnetized;` пока совершаются другие действия он `false`, когда `OnTriggerEnter2D` будет `true`...... соответственно пока этот параметр не `true` очередной запуск магнита не делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для более удобной работы с физикой. Есть компоненты `Effector'ы` в `2D` физике.
В качестве магнита можно использовать `Point Effector` или `Area Effector`. Не советую использовать `RayCast` в данном случае.
Так же не забудьте добавить `Collider2D` с установленной галочкой `Used By Effector`, в противном случае работать не будет.
`Collider` требуется для того, что бы обозначить зону работы `Effector'а`.

Для более подробного изучения, прочтите данный материал:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Physics2DReference.html

Или пройдите данный курс:
http://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/2d-physics-fun-with-effectors